# How can I change the next columns on a grid I created with outer and inner loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm a beginner Java student and feel like I've gotten pretty close to the end here. I've used the outer loop to create the first column and the inner loop to go across but I'm at a loss for how to make the other columns progress by 10 as well. The grid needs to print out each number in a sequence like this:
10-19
20-29 
30-39
40-49

Here is my code:

```
 >`for(int down = 10; down <=49; down +=10){
 >> System.out.print(down);
 >>>for(int across = 11; across <= 19; across++){
 >>>> System.out.print("\t" + across);
 >>> }
 >>>>System.out.println();`
```

This is printing out:

10 11-19
20 11-19
30 11-19
40 11-19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some arithmetic - `down + across`. This way, you're *always* iterating over the same `0-10` range with `across`:

```
for(int down = 10; down < 50; down += 10) {
  for(int across = 0; across < 10; across++) {
    System.out.print("\t" + (down + across));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Another way to do it might be to say `int across = down; while across < down + 10; across++` and then print just `across`.

Comment: That's it!!  (int across = down; across< down + 10; across++ ) did exactly that. Thank you so much!